# Grep with RegEx Inside a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, grep

Dipping my toes into Bash coding for the first time (*not the most experienced person with Linux either*) and I'm trying to read the version from the `version.php` inside a container at:

`/config/www/nextcloud/version.php`

**To do so, I run:**

```
docker exec -it 1c8c05daba19 grep -eo "(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?" /config/www/nextcloud/version.php
```

This uses a semantic versioning RegEx pattern (*I know, a bit overkill, but it works for now*) to read and extract the version from the line:

`$OC_VersionString = '20.0.1';`

However, when I run the command it tells me `No such file or directory`, (I've confirmed it *does* exist at that path inside the container) and then proceeds to spit out the entire contents of the file it just said doesn't exist?

> grep: (0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?: No such file or directory
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:$OC_Version = array(20,0,1,1);
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:$OC_VersionString = '20.0.1';
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:$OC_Edition = '';
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:$OC_VersionCanBeUpgradedFrom = array (
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:  'nextcloud' =>
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:  'owncloud' =>
> /config/www/nextcloud/version.php:$vendor = 'nextcloud';

Anyone able to spot the problem?

**Update 1:**

For the sake of clarity, I'm trying to run this from a bash script. I just want to fetch the version number from that file, to use it in other areas of the script.

**Update 2:**

Responding to the comments, I tried to login to the container first, and then run the grep, and still get the same result. Then I cat that file and it shows it's contents no problem.

[image]

Comment: docker exec -it command is used to login to the container and once you login then you can grep. so, first login to the container docker exec -it 1c8c05daba19 and then search with regexp

Comment: hmm , login into the container, check if the file exists, try to run the bash after you login, check if it working fine. 99% you may have made a simple mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for any potential future readers, I had no luck getting `grep` to do it, I'm sure it was my fault somehow and not grep's, but thanks to the help [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64609792/553663) I was able to use `awk` instead of `grep`, like so:

```
docker exec -it 1c8c05daba19 awk '/^\$OC_VersionString/ && match($0,/\047[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\047/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' /config/www/nextcloud/version.php
```

**That ended up doing exactly what I needed:**

- It logs into a docker container.
- Scans and returns just the version number from the line I am looking for at: `/config/www/nextcloud/version.php` inside the container.
- Exits stage left from the container with just the info I needed.
- I can get right back to eating my Hot Cheetos.

Answer (score 2):

Many containers don't have the GNU versions of Unix tools and their various extensions.  It's popular to base containers on Alpine Linux, which in turn uses a very lightweight single-binary tool called BusyBox to provide the base tools.  Those tend to have the set of options required in the POSIX specs, and no more.

POSIX [**grep**(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55) in particular doesn't have an `-o` option.  So the command you're running is

```sh
grep                                 \
  -eo                                \ # specify "o" as the regexp to match
  "(regexps are write-only)"         \ # a filename
  /config/www/nextcloud/version.php    # a second filename
```

Notice that the `grep` output in the interactive shell only contains lines with the letter "o", but not for example the line just containing `array`.

POSIX grep doesn't have an equivalent for GNU grep's [-o option](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/General-Output-Control.html#General-Output-Control)

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line. Output lines use the same delimiters as input....

but it's easy to do that with **sed**(1) instead.  Ask it to match some stuff, the regexp in question, and some stuff, and replace it with the matched group.

```sh
sed -e 's/.*\(any regexp here\).*/\1/' input-file
```

(POSIX [sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116) only accepts basic regular expressions, so you'll have to escape more of the parentheses.)

Comment: Thanks @David Maze, I had also thought of checking the version of grep inside the container just before reading your post and did a quick `grep --help`. And you're right, it uses a slimmed down busybox version that also looks like it needed a `-f` argument for the filename, but oddly, it does still have the `-o` argument. https://i.imgur.com/hKqEkei.png

I still can't get it working though, so I'll give your sed suggestion a shot.

Comment: Does this look right? `sed -e 's/.*\([0-9]{1,2}\)+[.]+\([0-9]{1,2}\)+[.]+\([0-9]{1,2}\).*/\1/' /config/www/nextcloud/version.php`. Trying a different regex, but when I use it, it just echos back the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Same result with more escaped chars: `sed -e 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\+[.]\+\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\+[.]\+\([0-9]\{1,2\}\).*/\1/' /config/www/nextcloud/version.php`