# Awk RegEx returning nada?

Tags: regex, awk

**So I have this text in a file named** `version.php`:

```
<?php
$OC_Version = array(20,0,1,1);
$OC_VersionString = '20.0.1';
$OC_Edition = '';
$OC_Channel = 'stable';
$OC_VersionCanBeUpgradedFrom = array (
  'nextcloud' =>
  array (
    '19.0' => true,
    '20.0' => true,
  ),
  'owncloud' =>
  array (
  ),
);
$OC_Build = '2020-10-24T08:39:55+00:00 89d88b3ea5b4049355e3c49d121f82e5e62bfc44';
$vendor = 'nextcloud';
```

**and I'm trying to get awk to return just the version number from the line:**

`$OC_VersionString = '20.0.1';`

**using (so far) this command:**

`awk -e '$1 ~ /[:digit:]+[:punct:][:digit:]+[:punct:][:digit:]+/ {print $0}' version.php`

**But, when I use it, nothing gets returned?**

This is my first time using awk, sooo, ... BRE feels "awk-warrrd" *nerk nerk nerk*

Anyone able to sort this out?

Comment: You can't use bare POSIX character classes, wrap them with bracket expressions, e.g. `[:digit:]` => `[[:digit:]]`. Then, you can easily see the value is in Field 3, you use `$1`. And lastly, you are not extracting the field, you print the whole record.

Comment: I think `+` to quantify "one or more" is an ERE, not a BRE quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^\$OC_VersionString/ && match($0,/\047[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\047/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}' Input_file
```

---

---

**More generic solution:** Adding one more generic solution, tested in GNU `awk` which will capture version number in case it has more minor version eg--> `20.2.0.1`(as an example) too.

```
awk '
/^\$OC_VersionString/ && match($0,/\047([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+\047/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}' Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:*** Checking condition `/^\$OC_VersionString/` to check if a line starts from `/$OC_VersionString/` then checking that regex present in `match` function of `awk`. `match` is a default function of `awk` where we provide regex to be matched and once we have matched regex it sets values of `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` default variables. Where `RSTART` is starting index point of matched regex AND `RLENGTH` is length of matched regex. Then printing sub string from current line whose starting point is `RSTART` till value of `RLENGTH`.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this `awk`:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*' '$1 == "$OC_VersionString" {
   gsub(/[^.0-9]+/, "", $2)
   print $2
}' file.php
```

```
20.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bare POSIX character classes, you should wrap them with bracket expressions, e.g. `[:digit:]` => `[[:digit:]]`, etc.

Then, you can see the value you want is located in Field 3, while you use `$1` to search for the match. And lastly, you are not extracting the field, you print the whole record with `{print $0}`. Also, it will still contain `'` and `';` if you do not use `gsub`.

If you want to fix your approach, you can use

```sh
s="\$OC_VersionString = '20.0.1';"
awk '$3 ~ /[[:digit:]]+[[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+[[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+/{gsub(/['"'"';]/,"", $3);print $3}' <<< "$s"
# => 20.0.1
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/dQhZrS).

However, `sed` solution solution [looks simpler](https://ideone.com/t0Hx5t) here:

```sh
sed -n "s/.*'\\(.*\\)'.*/\\1/p" <<< "$s"
sed -n "s/.*'\\([0-9.]*\\)'.*/\\1/p" <<< "$s"
```